# Can't attach disks to the vm with virsh

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I'm trying to attach 5 disks to a Vagrant vm with

virsh attach-disk ansible_default --source /var/lib/libvirt/images/ansible_default.img --target vdb --cache none

But i'm getting the following error:

"error: Failed to attach disk
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_add': Failed to get "write" lock"

In the virsh pool i have 2 volumes:

---

ansible_default.img                                              /var/lib/libvirt/images/ansible_default.img
generic-VAGRANTSLASH-centos9s_vagrant_box_image_4.2.16_box.img   /var/lib/libvirt/images/generic-VAGRANTSLASH-centos9s_vagrant_box_image_4.2.16_box.img

And this is my vagrantfile here:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
  #   libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => 'vdb', :bus => 'scsi'
  #   libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => 'vdc', :bus => 'scsi'
  #   libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => 'vdd', :bus => 'scsi'
  #   libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => 'vde', :bus => 'scsi'
  #   libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => 'vdf', :bus => 'scsi'
  # end
  config.vm.box = "generic/centos9s"
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SHELL
  end
```